# How to capture web table to language specific data structure without using external file in python

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, automation, dataset

I am working on Selenium automation. My Web application has a web table and few functions on screen which alters web table data, i.e. merges rows, add two rows, sorting on columns, many more like that. 
To validate every action, I need snap of web table, before and after action which I will be using to to compare with my expected result.

i.e. Table

```
row  col1 col2 col3
row1  1    2    3
row2  4    5    5
```

After clicking ADD button
result would be one row and out should be

```
row  col1 col2 col3
row1  5    7    8
```

I want to capture table before and after ADD button, I will do my calculation on before data and prepare output and compare my output with after action table, both should match.

Is there any way I can save web table with internal data type, data structure, in python without using an external file like, txt, excel, csv, etc.

I don't want to use any external APIs as it will go as production deployment

```
# For loop iterate through each Row
    for row in get_elements(self.browser, soPg.order_rows):
        if not get_webelement(row, soPg.order_table_columns).text:
            break
    # For each Row, iterate through each column
        for col in get_webelements(row, soPg.order_table_columns):
            print col.text,
```

I have currect code which goes through table and prints all the cell values but I want to capture entire web table as object

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Added more details to explain problem

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML and your code trials in the question area.

Comment: Added my working code which prints each cell values